# Regex to find/replace text of varying length

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

We are using a third-party proprietery software in our project. Between two major releases, the vendor decided to restrict access to one of the methods and provided an alternate method name with a different signature. Example as shown below

```
Object obj;

Old way: Method_A(obj);

New way: obj.Method_B();
```

Is it possible to use regex with linux sed to do a find/replace?

Eg:

**Method_A(** *abc* **);** ==> *abc* **.Method_B();**

**Method_A(** *m* **);** ==> *m* **.Method_B();**

**Method_A(** *xyz123* **);** ==> *xyz123* **.Method_B();**

This is what I have tried so far:

```
grep -R "Method_A(" . | sed -i 's/Method_A(^.{1,50}$/_____.Method_B(/g"
```

No matter what I try to specify for _____, I am not able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: try `sed -E 's/Method_A\(([^)]+)\)/\1.Method_B()/' file` and `sed -E 's/Method_A\( *([^) ]+) *\)/\1.Method_B()/' file` if you have spaces inside `()`

Comment: `grep -R "Method_A(" . | sed 's/Method_A([[:space:]]\(.*\)[[:space:]])/\1.Method_B()/'`

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following POSIX BRE `sed` regex:

```
sed 's/Method_A( \(.*\) );/\1.Method_B();/g'
```

If you need to apply your 1 to 50 chars in between `(` and `);` use

```
sed 's/Method_A( \(.\{1,50\}\) );/\1.Method_B();/g'
```

**Details**

- `Method_A(`  - matches `Method_A(`  substring
- `\(.*\)` - Capturing group 1 (referenced to with the `\1` backreference in the replacement pattern part): any 0 or more chars, as many as possible
- `);` - a  `);` substring

See an [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/72lnWU):

```
sed 's/Method_A( \(.*\) );/\1.Method_B();/g' <<< 'Method_A( abc );' # ==> abc.Method_B();
sed 's/Method_A( \(.*\) );/\1.Method_B();/g' <<< 'Method_A( m );' # ==> m.Method_B();
sed 's/Method_A( \(.*\) );/\1.Method_B();/g' <<< 'Method_A( xyz123 );' # ==> xyz123.Method_B();
```